# How to get start with NSIS Component

Tags: nsis

> Blockquote

Am new to NSIS. Already i have a windows application which contains Service, from there communication takes place and i have a created Setup Project which i developed using .NET. Now i want to know how to convert this Setup to NSIS setup. So far i have created Welcome page, License page and now i am stuck up in Components pages. Since my project contains many 3rd party dlls also. I don't know how to start with.  Can any suggest how to work with NSIS?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component page displays the named sections from your script and the user can choose which components to install:

```
Page components
Page instfiles

Section "Main Program"
SectionIn RO ; Read only, always installed
Setoutpath $instdir
File "myapp.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "Foo component"
Setoutpath $instdir\plugins
File "Foo.dll"
SectionEnd

Section "Bar component"
Setoutpath $instdir\plugins
File "Bar.dll"
SectionEnd
```